# Is there any way to have embeddable class in Spring Data Neo4j 4

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Is  any annotation like `javax.persistence.Embeddable` or  `javax.persistence.Embedded` in SDN4?

In the following domain, for example, I want to store properties of Address class in Person's node instead of creating node for every Address.

```
// @Embeddable
pulbic class Address{
   private String city;
   private String zip;
   ...
}

@NodeEntity
pulbic class Person{
   @GraphId
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   // @Embedded
   private Address address;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am waiting for this feature as well. I tried researching this a month ago or so. This is the best answer I could find was by writing a custom ConversionService and turning your "Address" -> String... which is really a hack but that is what everyone seems to be doing for now.

Moreover, this solution is NOT that bad as it sounds in the sense that is doesn't take long to implement however, the limitation is you will not be able to index the individual attributes on the Address entity that have been concatenated into an individual String field.

See: [Spring Data Neo4j - relationship properties on complex type class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813004/spring-data-neo4j-relationship-properties-on-complex-type-class-members/22814919#comment53432761_22814919)

Also See: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-240

I recommend you sign in to jira and vote this enhancement UP to possibly get the ball rolling on it faster maybe for SDN 4.1